# Angular 5: JavaScript CustomEvent (Polyfill)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, events

When I added the following code to main.ts, CustomEvent is not added to window object correctly. If I add CustomEvent using the JavaScript console it does. Incidentally, the issue occurs when I click on a button that triggers my custom event (called: "choice-click").

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

function CustomEvent ( event, params ) {
    params = params || { bubbles: false, cancelable: false, detail: undefined };
    var evt = document.createEvent( 'CustomEvent' );
    evt.initCustomEvent( event, params.bubbles, params.cancelable, params.detail );
    return evt;
}

CustomEvent.prototype = (<any>window).Event.prototype;

(<any>window).CustomEvent = CustomEvent;

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Below are two screen shots. First one, main.ts adds CustomEvent. Second one, I add CustomEvent using the JavaScript console.

**Note: $.isFunction returns "true" when I use the JavaScript console**

[image: First one]

[image: Second one]

Comment: I know there are polyfills available but I have the same issue using them.

Comment: It looks like you're using IE? Maybe Edge? Please clarify which browser you're experiencing this in. Also, the [Angular documentation lists some required polyfills](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#polyfill-libs)...

Comment: Yes, Internet Explorer 11. Edge works fine.

Comment: The function in main.ts was copied from a polyfill. It doesn't work when in main.ts but does work when I add CustomEvent using JavaScript console. Of course, I replace `(<any>window)` with `window` when in console because that is Typescript

Comment: You should take a look at [Angular 4 app not working on IE11 and edge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46291102)

Comment: The resolution required that I place CustomEvent *after* Angular 5 script bundling

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Angular CLI you can (as an alternative) install the "custom event polyfill" with `npm i custom-event-polyfill` and add it to your polyfills.ts: `import 'custom-event-polyfill';`

Comment: The resolution required that I place CustomEvent after Angular 5 script bundling –

Comment: I did this approach and added it to the component.  Getting an empty object back.  I can see everything in my node_modules.  Wondering if there is another file.

Answer (score 3):

Haven't any clue when I had to place the polyfill in line and after Angular but it works.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CustomEvent ( event, params ) {
        params = params || { bubbles: false, cancelable: false, detail: undefined };
        var evt = document.createEvent( 'CustomEvent' );
        evt.initCustomEvent( event, params.bubbles, params.cancelable, params.detail );
        return evt;
    }

    CustomEvent.prototype = window.Event.prototype;

    window.CustomEvent = CustomEvent;
</script>
```